# Apache 2: How to change http chunk size?

Tags: apache, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I believe Apache 2.x defaults to a http/1.1 chunk size of 8192 bytes?

I don't see a directive to change it - it there anything undocumented?

Also, is it possible to force a file to be chunked? Apache will typically not chunk a file if it knows the total size (like a static image). Can this behavior be changed?

Answer (score 3):

I saw HTTP File Server(http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/?f=dl) can change chunk-size by modifying  MAXIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE and MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE in hslib.pas.

You should find "8192" in Apache HTTP's source code first.
Hope it can give some help.